# Is $\Gamma(\alpha k+1)t^{\beta k}-\Gamma(\beta k+1)t^{\alpha k}>0$ true?

Tags: inequality, gamma-function

$$\Gamma(\alpha k+1)t^{\beta k}-\Gamma(\beta k+1)t^{\alpha k}>0$$

where $0<\alpha<\beta,$ $0<k,t$, $\Gamma(z)$ is a gamma function, $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$, $Re$ $z>0$.

I don't know even how to approach it. any hint, advise, counterexample, or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a conjecture of yours?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva yes. it is needed for my research, though unsolvable for me. :p

Comment: Ohoh, I see. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $t=1$, then you easily find many counter examples because $\Gamma(x)$ is 
increasing for $x>1.462$. E.g. with $\alpha=2,\,\beta=3,\,k=1,\,t=1$
$$\Gamma(\alpha k+1)t^{\beta k}-\Gamma(\beta k+1)t^{\alpha k}
=\Gamma(3)-\Gamma(4)=2-6=-4$$